# How to put extension methods in a library?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, projects-and-solutions

I wanted to have the removeAll method to remove items in a observableCollection. The code is:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int Remove<T>(
        this ObservableCollection<T> coll, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        var itemsToRemove = coll.Where(condition).ToList();

        foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
        {
            coll.Remove(itemToRemove);
        }

        return itemsToRemove.Count;
    }
}
```

I have my main project and I created a new DLL project with utilities related with collections, so I created in this second project a class that has this code.

However, I don't have the RemoveAll method in available to the observableCollection, I mean that:

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> o = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
o.RemoveAll ??
```

Is not available. I add a new reference in my main project to the second project and I include the using of the library.

If in my main project I create a class then the method is available. But I would like to have a library with this extension methods to have this methods to another project and not to add a new class in each project.

Comment: It should be absolutely fine. Are you *certain* you've included the relevant `using` directive? If you type `ExtensionMethods.` does Intellisense pop up with the `Remove` method? (Note that you haven't declared a `RemoveAll` method; you've declared a `Remove` method.)

Comment: true, but it's not the problem. The problem is the name of the static class. If I change ExtensionMethods to ObservableCollection then I have available the method.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía I really doubt that, as the method is not named `RemoveAll`, but `Remove`. See my answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: No, the name of the class really shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did not implement a `RemoveAll` method, but a `Remove<T>` method.

```
public static int Remove<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll, Func<T, bool> condition)
```

Maybe if you declare it like this...?

```
public static int RemoveAll<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll, Func<T, bool> condition)
```

Also, of course you have to reference the DLL in your original project and include the namespace.

What strikes me funny is that you say it works when you change the class name from `ExtensionMethods` to `ObservableCollection`. Could it be that you accidentially created a class named `ObservableCollection` that now conflicts with `System.Collections.Generic.ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I am surprise too, there is no conflict with the names. Firstly I was using a differnt name for that, but I tried to change the name and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the namespace with "using" keyword.
For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: The OP already said that he has _"include[d] the using of the library"_. So your answer provides nothing that the OP doesn't already know. I suggest you be more explicit about *which* namespace to import.